# How to read a json file into build.gradle and use the values the strings in build.gradle file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

for example,
read the json file in `build.gradle` and use the json values as strings in the file

```
{
  "type":"xyz",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
      "type": "pqr"
     },
     "bar": {
       "type": "abc"
     },
     "baz": {
       "type": "lmo"
     }
  }
}
```

I need to call `properties.bar.type` and `abc` should be replaced there.

I need to convert these values to `string` and use in `build.gradle` file

Comment: AnimiVulpis : He probably wants to have some key value, but unable to find the a way from gradle task to read json.

Answer (score 40):

**From Gradle you can execute any Groovy code and Groovy already has build-in JSON parsers.**

E.g. you can use a task that will print your value into stdout:

```groovy
task parseJson {
    doLast {
        def jsonFile = file('path/to/json')
        def parsedJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonFile.text)

        println parsedJson.properties.bar.type
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As with Gradle 8.3 Kotlin is official DSL language, I'm extending the answer in case you are using `buils.gradle.kts` script file

Kotlin doesn't include JSON serialization component in the [base language itself](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html). You have to include dependency to `kotlin-serialization-json`. As you need this dependency in your script you have to include it through the `buildscript{}` block.

Solution that prints your value with Gradle logger:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.json.*
import java.nio.charset.Charset

plugins {
    id("base")
}
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.6.0")
    }
}

tasks.register("readFromJson") {
    doLast {
        // Read json file
        val jsonFile = project.file("jsonFile.json")
        // Convert into immutable JSON object
        val fileAsJsonObject = Json.decodeFromString<JsonObject>(jsonFile.readText(Charset.defaultCharset())); 
        // Read properties.bar.type and print to Gradle logger
        logger.quiet("properties.bar.type value: " + fileAsJsonObject["properties"]?.jsonObject?.get("bar")?.jsonObject?.get("type"))
    }
}
```

Or you can mix and still use Groovy `JsonSlurper` class withing Kotlin DSL. While in Kotlin you have to expect the type of nodes in JSON.

```kotlin
import org.apache.groovy.json.internal.LazyMap

tasks.register("readFromJson") {
    doLast {
        // Read json file
        val jsonFile = project.file("jsonFile.json")
        // Convert into LazyMap at a root level
        val fileAsJsonObject =  groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonFile.readText()) as LazyMap
        logger.quiet("properties.bar.type value: S" +
                (((fileAsJsonObject["properties"] as LazyMap)["bar"] as LazyMap))["type"]
        )
    }
}
```