# I have problem when write groovy code in Android gradle file

Tags: gradle, groovy, nashorn

I'am trying to parse json file in gradle task using JsonSlurper in a Android project, but the Android Studio prompt that "Cannot resolve symbol 'JsonSlurper'".

My question is since gradle is based on groovy,it shuld be able to use groovy APIs like JsonSlurper in it, why Android Studio din't recognize the groovy.json.JsonSlurper(), 
I searched several answers here, 
[How to read a json file into build.gradle and use the values the strings in build.gradle file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034992/how-to-read-a-json-file-into-build-gradle-and-use-the-values-the-strings-in-buil/39040755) and 
[groovy.json.JsonSlurper parse JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953522/groovy-json-jsonslurper-parse-json)
The answers also reommend using JsonSlurper, how they achieve that?

My Android Studio Version is 3.4, gradle version is gradle-4.10.1,
here is the content of my gradle file:

```
ext {
    destPath = project.rootDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/output/"
    configPath = project.rootDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/script/"
}

task myClean(type: Delete) {
    delete(destPath)
}
task minifyTask(dependsOn: myClean) << {
    def configFile = new File(configPath + 'config.cfg')
    ddef parsedJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(configFile.text)

}
```

I expect to use JsonSlurper to parse json file in gradle file normally

Comment: It doesn't work from both IDE and command line?

Comment: It work from the command line@Opal , why not recognized by Android Studio

Comment: It works for me (Gradle 2.9). What version are you using? By the way you have a typo in your code, you wrote `ddef` instead of `def`.